# Why does my script write every input string twice to the output file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I look at what it wrote it's always double. For example if I write 'dog' ill get 'dogdog'. Why?

Reading and writing to file, filename taken from command line arguments:

```
from sys import argv

script,text=argv

def reading(f):
    print f.read()

def writing(f):
    print f.write(line)

filename=open(text)
#opening file 

reading(filename)

filename.close()

filename=open(text,'w')

line=raw_input()

filename.write(line)

writing(filename) 

filename.close()
```

As I said the output I am getting is the double value of what input I am giving.

Comment: You are writing to the file twice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to display each line and then write a new line, you should probably just read the entire file first, and then loop over the lines when writing new content.

Here's how you can do it. When you use `with open()`, you don't have to `close()` the file, since that's done automatically.

```
from sys import argv
filename = argv[1]

# first read the file content
with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

# `lines` is now a list of strings.

# then open the file for writing. 
# This will empty the file so we can write from the start.
with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
    # by using enumerate, we can get the line numbers as well.
    for index, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        print 'line %d of %d:\n%s' % (index, len(lines),  line.rstrip())
        new_line = raw_input()
        fp.write(new_line + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: No mention of *why* the file is being written to twice. See @bhansa 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting double value because you are writing two times

1) From the Function call

```
def writing(f):
    print f.write(line)
```

2) By writing in file using `filename.write(line)`

Use this code:

```
from sys import argv

script,text=argv

def reading(f):
    print f.read()

def writing(f):
    print f.write(line)

filename=open(text,'w')

line=raw_input()

writing(filename) 

filename.close()
```

And also no need to close file two times, once you finished all the read and write operations then just close it.

Comment: Well I wanted to display what is in the file and write over it some other text.